# BASH - Create arrays from lines of csv file, where first entry is array name

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, variables

I'm learning to script in Bash.
I have an CSV file, which contains next lines:

```
numbers,one,two,three,four,five
colors,red,blue,green,yellow,white
custom-1,a,b,c,d,e
custom+2,t,y,w,x,z
```

Need to create arrays from this, where first entry is array name, eg.

```
number=(one,two,three,four,five)
colors=(red,blue,green,yellow,white)
custom-1=(a,b,c,d,e)
custom+2=(t,y,w,x,z)
```

Here is my script:

```
IFS=","
while read NAME VALUES ; do
    declare -a $NAME
    arrays+=($NAME)
    IFS=',' read -r -a $NAME <<< "${VALUES[0]}"
done < file.csv
```

When I try with csv file, containing only two first string (numbers and colors), code works well. And if i try to with number, colors, custom-1, custom-2, there is error during reading csv:

```
./script.sh: line 5: declare: `custom-1': not a valid identifier
./script.sh: line 7: read: `custom+2': not a valid identifier
```

because bash does not allow special characters in variable names, as far as I understand. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: No. You have to rename the variables. Bash does not have nested arrays either. And you can not put the array into a hash value.

Comment: Your first array shall be named `numbers`, not `number`. And bash variables cannot have any name. Forget about `custom-1` or `custom+2`, they are invalid variable names, as the error messages say. Either modify these names such that they become valid variable names, or create valid array names with, e.g., a counter, and store the names you are interested in as keys of an associative array, where the values would be the counter. This way you could recover the real array name from the text of the first column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you cannot use the first column of your CSV file as bash array names one option would be to generate valid names using a counter (e.g. `arrayN`). If you want to access your data using the values of this first column you would also need to store them somewhere with the corresponding counter value. An associative array (`declare -A names=()`) would be perfect. Last but not least, the namerefs (`declare -n arr=...`, available starting with bash 4.3) will be convenient to store and access your data. Example:

```sh
declare -i cnt=1
declare -A names=()
while IFS=',' read -r -a line; do
  names["${line[0]}"]="$cnt"
  declare -n arr="array$cnt"
  unset line[0]
  declare -a arr=( "${line[@]}" )
  ((cnt++))
done < foo.csv
```

Now, to access the values corresponding to, let's say, entry `custom+2`, first get the corresponding counter value, declare a nameref pointing to the corresponding array and voilà:

```
$ cnt="${names[custom+2]}"
$ declare -n arr="array$cnt"
$ echo "${arr[@]}"
t y w x z
```

Let's declare a function for easier access:

```sh
getdata () {
  local -i cnt="${names[$1]}"
  local -n arr="array$cnt"
  [ -z "$2" ] && echo "${arr[@]}" || echo "${arr[$2]}"
}
```

And then:

```sh
$ getdata "custom+2"
t y w x z
$ getdata "colors"
red blue green yellow white
$ getdata "colors" 3
yellow
```

Comment: `declare -n` is useful but needs bash 4.3

Comment: @Fravadona Right. I added a note about this, thanks.